# Aligning header in CSS

Tags: css

I have a problem with my header. Namely, the nav tag goes below the logo and I don't know how to align it. I tried adjusting the nav with padding but this did not work eventually.

CSS:

```
    html body {
      font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
      color: DimGrey;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0 24px;
      width: auto;
    }
    
    /*
    header {
      height: 64px;
      margin: 10px 24px 10px 24px;
      }
    */
    
    nav {
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    nav li {
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0 16px 0 0;
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    p {
      font-size: 14px;
      padding: 8px 0;
    }
    
    .name1, .name2 {
      font-size: 32px;
      display: flex;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: lighter;
    }
    
    .name1 {
      color: DarkGrey;
    }
    
    .logo {
      display: flex;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .imglogo {
      height: 50px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
```

Please advise what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to the stackoverflow, Monica. Can you setup a demo on codepen / jsfiddle / or similar service? It's not that easy to find out what went wrong just looking at css or github code because problem is very specific.

Answer (score 0):

Add this style below to your CSS:

```
header{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
```